# ELF relocation on ARM Cortex-M3

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, elf, relocation

I'm trying to figure out how relocation works, but I can't seem to get my head around it.
[This document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044f/IHI0044F_aaelf.pdf#page=28) describes the different types one can encounter when relocating an ELF file.

Let's take `R_ARM_ALU_SB_G0_NC` (#70) for example.

- Type: static
- Class: ARM, describes the type of place being relocated (which I do not understand)
- Operation: ((S + A) | T) – B(S))

I'm guessing that the mathematical expression is the operation I'm looking for. However, I do not completely understand how this fits in my function.
The method where the relocation takes place looks as follows:

```
int elfloader_arch_relocate(int input_fd, struct elfloader_output *output,
    unsigned int sectionoffset, char *sectionaddr, struct elf32_rela *rela, char *addr)
```

`input_fd` is a file descriptor for the ELF file, `*output` is used when writing the output segment, `sectionoffset` is the file offset at which the relocation can be found, `*sectionaddr` is the section start address (absolute runtime) and `*addr` is the relocated address.
The 32-bit relocation structure looks like this

```
 struct elf32_rela {
   elf32_addr   r_offset;
   elf32_word   r_info;
   elf32_sword  r_addend;
 };
```

On page 26 of the above mentioned [document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044f/IHI0044F_aaelf.pdf#page=28) the nomenclature is explained:

- S (when used on its own) is the address of the symbol.
- A is the addend for the relocation.
- T is 1 if the target symbol S has type STT_FUNC and the symbol addresses a Thumb instruction; it is 0 otherwise.
- B(S) is the addressing origin of the output segment defining the symbol

So my question is, which of the parameters in the relocate function correspond to the ones used in the formula?

Comment: where are you doing the relocation, do you have an operating system with an elf parser on the cortex-m3?

Comment: I'm using Contiki OS 2.7, so I only need to write some processor dependent functions, like `elfloader_arch_relocate()`

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are implementing a _linker_ or a _loader_. A linker runs as the last stage of compilation, to transform "object files" into "executables" and "shared libraries".  A loader runs as the first stage of execution, to "fix up" executables and shared libraries as they are brought into memory.  A linker has to handle many more relocation types than a loader. Please say which you mean.

Comment: I'm implementing a dynamic loader, to load the object files at runtime

Comment: What use would that have. Most CM3 MCUs have use only internal Flash. And dynacially loading code to an embedded system welcomes malware and other trouble.

Comment: It is used in wireless sensor networks. Program code typically consists of around 100 kilobytes, so updates of a few kilobytes can be loaded directly in flash memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, and I'm not sure I am, it goes like this:

- `S` is `addr`.
- `B(S)` is `sectionaddr`.
- `A` is `rela->r_addend`.
- `T` *may* be derivable from information in `rela->r_info`; if not, I don't know where you need to look.

This is a really complicated-looking relocation.  Consider starting with the simple ones (like `R_ARM_ABS16`).  In a dynamic loader, you should *not* have to implement all of the relocation typess in the spec you linked to, only a small subset.  If it seems like you need a lot of relocation types, this is probably because you are trying to feed *unlinked object files* to the dynamic loader; you should turn them into shared objects, using your existing ARM linker.  (With the GNU toolchain, a first approximation to how you do that is `gcc -shared foo.o -o foo.so`.)

Cribbing off an existing dynamic loader for the architecture is often a good plan; there tends to be a lot of undocumented wisdom buried in the code for such things.  For instance, here is [GNU libc's ld.so's ARM relocator](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/arm/dl-machine.h;h=2c72972bd22723c82ae4ae897604fd7f8da9c207;hb=4fee33f8c11447d345b2b1118a98958b54d5fda3).  (LGPL)

Comment: When I'm testing the current implementation, I get an error about an unsupported relocation type (#70). Is it possible to overcome this error by using simpler relocations then?

Comment: Not in the long run, but while you're still bringing this implementation up, you can test on shared objects of progressively increasing complexity.

Comment: (It's possible that you are trying to feed an unlinked object file to a loader, which is not something that is supposed to work in the first place. Please see comments on the question.)